# Running private_pub with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, faye, private-pub

I have an app that uses the private_pub gem (which uses faye) for sending notifications to users.
The problem is that I'm trying to deploy using docker and docker-compose (since there's quite a few things needed such as solr searching and redis). 
As long as everything was running under localhost, everything was fine. But now my webserver is running in a docker container, as well as all other services. I've tried starting a container for faye, but then the publishing or subscribing doesn't work.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: rails server -e development -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
     - solr:solr
     - mariadb
     - redis
    depends_on:
      - solr
    env_file:
      - .env
  solr:
    image: solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - qwerteach
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379"
  faye:
    image: nickjj/faye
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "9292:9292"
    environment:
      FAYE_PUSH_TOKEN: "secret"
      FAYE_PORT: 9292
      FAYE_MOUNT: "/faye"
      FAYE_LOGGING: 1

volumes:
  data:
  mariadb:
```

And my private_pub.yml

```
development:
  server: "http://faye:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
test:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "secret"
production:
  server: "http://example.com/faye"
  secret_token: "9eba1078bbb9289f949f51abc7ed5f842fed3af11374056bf09799e4ef2733f2"
  signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

With this configuration, from the "outside" (meaning a dumb terminal) I can contact faye:
`curl -X POST http://localhost:9292/faye     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'     -d '{"channel": "/foo", "data": "Hello", "ext": {"pushToken": "secret"}}'` is successful
It also works from the docker web container, but with a different address:

```
curl -X POST http://faye:9292/faye     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'     -d '{"channel": "/foo", "data": "Hello", "ext": {"pushToken": "secret"}}'
```

However the private_pub.yml config file only allows one address... So either subscribing to channels works for clients but I can't publish from controllers, or I can publish from controllers but users can't subscribe. How can I solve this?

Any help would be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case someone is trying to run private_pub in a dockerized rails app, here's how I got it running:

- open port 9292 of the web container
- from the web container, run the rackup command `rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -o 0.0.0.0`
  Explicitly telling thin to use host 0.0.0.0 is the key, that's how it'll be available from the outside on port 9292 (same as the rails container that's available on port 3000)

The in the private_pub.yml, parameters are as follow:

```
production:
  server: "http://production.server.ip:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "this_is_a_very_secret_token"
```

Not sure it's the best way to do it, but it's the only way I could make it work ; And after 3 days of searching and too much coffee, I'm not going to ask for more.